# Docker Wordpress Setup with Volume for Theme Folder

Tags: wordpress, docker

I created a setup for a wordpress installation with docker-compose:

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:8.0
    container_name: db
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - dbdata-dev:/var/lib/mysql
    command: '--default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password'
    networks:
      - rn-dev-network

  wordpress:
    depends_on:
      - db
    image: wordpress:5.5.3-fpm-alpine
    container_name: wordpress
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=db:3306
      - WORDPRESS_DB_USER=$MYSQL_USER
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=$MYSQL_PASSWORD
      - WORDPRESS_DB_NAME=$MYSQL_DATABASE
    volumes:
      - ./wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./wordpress/uploads.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/uploads.ini
      - wordpress-dev:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - rn-dev-network

  webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress-dev:/var/www/html
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - rn-dev-network

volumes:
  wordpress-dev:
  dbdata-dev:

networks:
  rn-dev-network:
    driver: bridge
```

Via FTP, I moved a theme into the wp-content/themes folder. The theme shows up on wordpress when starting the container, but it does not show any preview picture and is missing all pictures/assets when loading it.

I don't see what is missing. When I ssh into the container and check the folder, the volume is correctly linked and the wordpress theme is showing up in the correct folder.

[Preview Screen of Wordpress Theme Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yj8SE.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to mount the image file to the nginx container, because static content is served via the nginx container.
The Php container only executes the php.

```yaml
webserver:
    depends_on:
      - wordpress
    image: nginx:1.15.12-alpine
    container_name: webserver
    restart: unless-stopped
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    volumes:
      - wordpress-dev:/var/www/html
      - ./wordpress/wp-content:/var/www/html/wp-content
      - ./nginx-conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
    networks:
      - rn-dev-network
```